# MDN: Why isn't defining method on object constructor function ideal?

Tags: javascript, oop

```js
function Person(name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.greeting = function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  };
}
```

```js
let person1 = new Person('Bob');
let person2 = new Person('Sarah');
```

Copy to Clipboard

"After the new objects have been created, the person1 and person2 variables contain the following objects:"

```js
{
  name: 'Bob',
  greeting: function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  }
}

{
  name: 'Sarah',
  greeting: function() {
    alert('Hi! I\'m ' + this.name + '.');
  }
}
```

Copy to Clipboard
"Note that when we are calling our constructor function, we are defining greeting() every time, which isn't ideal. To avoid this, we can define functions on the prototype instead, which we will look at later."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS
MDN says defining greeting every time isn't ideal. I don't understand, we only define greeting once on the constructor function? What is not ideal about this?

Comment: Every time you call a new instance of `Person`,  the function gets defined again

Comment: @gbac so it is more of a performance issue instead of code structure issue? because the function gets defined again instead of referenced?

Comment: It's unnecessary redundancy, which can cause performance issues, but also is not considered 'best practice' when it comes to code structure.. So both